# Realm object in multiple screens

Tags: android, realm

I intergrate Realm to my project. I have problem like this (my allication is like asking question and answering)

I have a A screen with list of questions, I get questions from web serivice, after that I store them to Realm, get and show them. I have another B sccreen, still get questions, store and show questions, but it  has the same some  questions like A screen. 
So I create object `Question` like this

```
class Question {
   boolean at_screen_A;
   boolean at_screen_B;

   String id;
   ...
}
```

1. I want to know when will I delete questions in realm, when pull to
   refresh? Now based on at_screen_A, and at_screen_B I delete question
   or not. Is this right for other popular app like facebook, ... ?
2. How to load more because list of questions in Realm only get list
       references and using lazy loading, don't have limit data.

Comment: If you are running on looper threads, Realm is automatically refreshed.

Comment: Showing more is handled by [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), is it not?